# Conditionally set a SQLCMD variable in a scriptfile?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I need to conditionally set a SQCMD scripting variable depending on the machine name.

I have  a SQLCMD command as follows

```
sqlcmd  -U "username" -S "ipaddr" -P "password" -i "scriptname"
```

In the script scriptname, the psuedocode of what I want to achieve is:

```
IF SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') = "X"
  :setvar USER User1
ELSE
  :setvar USER User2
```

so that the USER can be used in subsequent statements as $(USER), currently in many existing lines of code

I won't list all the failed attempts, but I can't get the correct syntax of mixing SQLCMD with TSQL.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCMD variable values are assigned by the tool before the batch is sent to SQL Server for execution. Consequently, it is not possible to set the value, conditionally or otherwise, using T-SQL (which runs on the server).

One workaround is to invoke SQLCMD twice, once to create the `SETVAR` commands using T-SQL and pipe it to a file on the client and then to execute the final script that include the file using the ':r' SQLCMD command. Example (which could be encapsulated in an OS command file):

```
sqlcmd -U "username" -S "ipaddr" -P "password" -I -Q"IF SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') = 'X' PRINT ':setvar USER User1' ELSE PRINT ':setvar USER User1';" >"C:\Scripts\setvarcommands.sql"
sqlcmd -U "username" -S "ipaddr" -P "password" -I -i "C:\Scripts\scriptname.sql"
```

Contents of c:\Scripts\scriptname.sql:

```
:r "C:\Scripts\setvarcommands.sql"
PRINT '$(USER)';
```

There may be more elegant ways to create the setvarcommands.sql but this is the first that came to mind.

Note that I specified the `-I` SQLCMD parameter so that `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS ON` is used for script execution. The default is OFF for backwards compatibility and may result in issues with some DDL or DML operations. I recommend -I' always be specified.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. This is close and I could develop this approach. Sqlcmd line ran ok and created the setvarcommands.sql file, When it is imported and run I get error ...The name "User1" is not permitted in theis context. Vaild expressions are constants, constant expressions and (in some case) variables. Column names are not permitted......      I think User1 has to be in double quotes, ie ':setvar USER "User1"' but this gives me incorrect syntax error when running the sqlcmd to create the setvarcommands.sql file

Comment: That's a T-SQL error so you might not be using the SQLCMD variable properly in the scri[pt. Post the T-SQL snippent that uses the T-SQL command variable.

Comment: setvarcommand.sql
:setvar USER "aaa_bbb-cxx"
My first problem is that my "User1" is actually of the format "aaa_bbb-cxx" and the :r "C:Scripts\setvarcommands.sql" reads the file but sets the USER to "aaa_bbb". I can't find a way to escape the "-" (or is it the "-c" I need to escape ?)

But the next error is occurring on the :r command

Even if I change USER to
setvarcommand.sql
:setvar USER "aaa_bbb" I still get an errr on the :r command

Comment: scriptname.sql is

PRINT N'Getting USER'
GO
:r "C:\Projects\aaa\bbb\ccc\setvarcommands.sql"
PRINT N'USER = ' + $(USER);

Output is

Getting USER
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Server MyServer, Line 1
The name "aaa_bbb" is not permitted in this context. Vaild expressions are constants, constant expressions and (in some case) variables. Column names are not permitted.

I have changed the identifier USER to ASDFGFH just to ensure I'm not getting a valid column name or a reserved word, but get the same error

Comment: @mikec, SQLCMD variables are different than T-SQL variables. `$(USER)` in the script becomes `aaa_bbb-cxx`, just like a text search/replace. So your `PRINT` statement is becomes `PRINT N'USER = ' + aaa_bbb-cxx; ` at run time, which is invalid T-SQL. It should be `PRINT 'USER=$(User)';`, similar to the example in my answer.